# What is used on Lion version for SMB sharing?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, smb

I know that Apple has changed implementation for SAMBA sharing on Lion Version. I am trying to share folder programmatically. IT works on Snow Leopard.

But it doesn't on Lion, can you give me a clue, what Apple used for SMB sharing on Lion version? And where does it store information about shared folders using SMB.

Comment: I noticed that you tagged this under cocoa. I'd suggest that this get moved to stackoverflow if you're referring to system/API calls in an obj-c cocoa project that no longer work under Lion.

Comment: ?? There's no Cocoa API for folder sharing, SMB or otherwise. The question as it stands doesn't belong on StackOverflow. I would think maybe superuser.com would be the better place to answer it as is.

Comment: This should have stayed on Ask Different, but with the cocoa tag removed, since there is no other indication that it has anything to do with programming.

Comment: There is mention of "programmatically", but he's not asking the question "how do I mount a smb share in Lion in code"...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [report from AppleInsider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/23/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_server_apple_replaces_samba_for_windows_networking_services.html).

Apple has replaced SAMBA with their own proprietary internally-developed code, called SMBX, apparently largely due to not being able to comply with the SAMBA project's open-source licensing requirements.

I am not aware of any documentation released by Apple, but I don't have a developer account.